# SQl Server indexing, same column 2 different indexes?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 queries I need to run against my DB.  One looks for ManufacturerID and the other looks for ManufacturerID and SalesRepID.

Should I have 1 index on ManufacturerID and 1 index on SalesRepID

OR

1 Index on ManufacturerID and 1 Index on ManufacturerID and SalesRepID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If your table is big enough, and your data is sparse enough, it might make sense to have:

1. Index on `ManufacturerID`
2. Index on `ManufacturerID`, `SalesRepID`

On the other hand, if you have just a few different `SalesRepID` for each `ManufacturerID`, then both queries will be probably very well optimized just by using index on `ManufacturerID`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd only need one index on both one index on ManufacturerID and SalesRepID.

A search on ManufacturerID should still use this composite index as long it is the left hand column on the index key columns.